# VB.Net Regex: Make operator apply to whole word, but not return it

Tags: regex, vb.net, vb6, operators, quantifiers

I'm looking to make a regex with an operator that applies to a whole word. For example, I want the word hello to be optional. Instead of having `h?e?l?l?o?`, I am wondering if it is possible to write something like `(hello)?`*.

**Note that `(hello)?` does not work for my case since I do not want hello to be returned in the matches.*

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you want a non-capturing group, which is achieved using `?:` at the start of the group:

```
(?:hello)?
```

See the [MSDN guide to grouping constructs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you have a capturing group within a non-capturing group like this (?:word(.*))

Comment: @UrielKatz: I don't know - but it shouldn't be hard to try :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Just tried it; yes, you can have a capturing group within a non-capturing group.